# R data.table create list column by group

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` below, and I would like to apply a function to column `v2` group by `v1` and `order`, the resulting column `v3` should be a list of vectors below.

How do I write this function such that it will return a vector of 0s for each group's first row `(order == 1 & v1 %in% c(1, 2))`. For each subsequent row in the group, the vector will append previous row's `v2` value to the right of the vector while bumping off one `0` from the left.

Initial `data.table`

```
t3 <- data.table(
  v1 = rep(1:2, each = 5),
  order = rep(1:5, 2),
  v2 = c(6, 9, 6, 8, 6, 2, 5, 7, 8, 2)
)

    v1 order v2
 1:  1     1  6
 2:  1     2  9
 3:  1     3  6
 4:  1     4  8
 5:  1     5  6
 6:  2     1  2
 7:  2     2  5
 8:  2     3  7
 9:  2     4  8
10:  2     5  2
```

applying the function...

output:

```
t3[, v3 := list(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                c(0, 0, 0, 0, 6),
                c(0, 0, 0, 6, 9),
                c(0, 0, 6, 9, 6),
                c(0, 6, 9, 6, 8),
                c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                c(0, 0, 0, 0, 2),
                c(0, 0, 0, 2, 5),
                c(0, 0, 2, 5, 7),
                c(0, 2, 5, 7, 8))]

    v1 order v2        v3
 1:  1     1  6 0,0,0,0,0
 2:  1     2  9 0,0,0,0,6
 3:  1     3  6 0,0,0,6,9
 4:  1     4  8 0,0,6,9,6
 5:  1     5  6 0,6,9,6,8
 6:  2     1  2 0,0,0,0,0
 7:  2     2  5 0,0,0,0,2
 8:  2     3  7 0,0,0,2,5
 9:  2     4  8 0,0,2,5,7
10:  2     5  2 0,2,5,7,8
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could try

```
t3[order(order), .(order, v2, shift(v2, 5:1, fill = 0)), by = v1]
```

Output:

```
    v1 order v2        V3
 1:  1     1  6 0,0,0,0,0
 2:  1     2  9 0,0,0,0,6
 3:  1     3  6 0,0,0,6,9
 4:  1     4  8 0,0,6,9,6
 5:  1     5  6 0,6,9,6,8
 6:  2     1  2 0,0,0,0,0
 7:  2     2  5 0,0,0,0,2
 8:  2     3  7 0,0,0,2,5
 9:  2     4  8 0,0,2,5,7
10:  2     5  2 0,2,5,7,8
```

Comment: This is excellent answer! I didn't know you could create a list using `shift`. Thank you, thank you, thank you!!

Comment: You are welcome. Matt & Company have done an excellent job,  ´data.table´ is awesome!