# data.table from long colum to list by grup

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to "paste" all values by group into a list. Something similar to what paste(x, collapse="-") does, but the output should be a list. I managed to do this into two steps. Can it be done in one step?

```
library("data.table")

d <- data.table( sample(letters, 100, replace = T), sample(LETTERS,100, replace = T)) %>%    unique

d[, paste0(V2, collapse = "--"), by=V1] %>% head
    V1               V1
1:  m       E--T--L--Q
2:  k    J--H--W--P--X
3:  v          D--W--X
4:  g          H--E--I
5:  c K--U--X--H--Y--N
6:  l    O--H--J--R--U

dd <- split(d, by="V1", keep.by=FALSE)
data.table(names(dd), sapply(dd, "[") ) %>% head
   V1          V2
1:  m     E,T,L,Q
2:  k   J,H,W,P,X
3:  v       D,W,X
4:  g       H,E,I
5:  c K,U,X,H,Y,N
6:  l   O,H,J,R,U
```

I tried with shift as well, with no sucess [R data.table create list column by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53415886/r-data-table-create-list-column-by-group)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can wrap it in a `list`

```
dd <- d[, .(V2 = list(V2)), V1]
head(dd)
#   V1              V2
#1:  c     Z,W,K,G,Q,A
#2:  a       V,X,T,D,K
#3:  w           Z,I,N
#4:  u N,Y,H,U,M,Z,...
#5:  d         G,M,D,B
#6:  q O,Z,K,V,I,X,...

str(dd)
#Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 25 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ V1: chr  "c" "a" "w" "u" ...
# $ V2:List of 25
#  ..$ : chr  "Z" "W" "K" "G" ...
#  ..$ : chr  "V" "X" "T" "D" ...
#  ..$ : chr  "Z" "I" "N"
#  ..$ : chr  "N" "Y" "H" "U" ...
#  ..$ : chr  "G" "M" "D" "B"
# ..
```

Comment: sorry for the imprecise description, it should be a list containing a vector of strings, not a list containing one string.

Comment: now I realized why this was not working when I first tried. The original intention was to modify the table by reference, so that each entry will have a list. Can this be achieved without merging in a second step?